# Iphone web service get response

Tags: iphone

In my Iphone app ,how to read the purchaseUrl and purchaseUrl2  and on button click download them  to my computer or iphone :

JSON-message output:
{
“PurchaseUrl” : 480p URL
“PurchaseUrl2” : 720p URL
}

Answer (score 0):

1. That's not [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)
2. See [Apple's downloading guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) using NSURLConnection.
3. Use the [JSON framework for iphone](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). - See [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/json-framework-for-iphone.html).
4. This is a duplicate of so many questions... please google before you ask.